# Restrict rows included in a SQL Server full text catalog

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

Is it possible to restrict the *rows* that are included in a FT catalog for a given table?
For example, I would want only rows with IsActive=TRUE to contribute to the catalog and be searchable.

Possibly this may reveal a lack of understanding on my part of FTS. I'm wondering whether there would be advantages in performance if the catalog size was kept quite lean. I'm aware that I could move the rows I don't want cataloged into another table if I really wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can [create an indexed view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) (Note that there are significant restrictions on when you can create an indexed view) that filters the table in the way that you want, you could then [create a full text index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx) on that view.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I'll explore that possibility. After a quick look at the criteria for creating an indexed view, I think it will fit the bill for this requirement.